# Load state with async action Vuex

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, async-await, vuex

I can't realize how to get it works.

I'm trying to load a propertie (productos) on my data() which has to catch the value from a state.

My component:

```
    data () {
        return {
          productos: this.$store.state.mStock.productos
        }
     },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchProductos')
  }
```

At this point i think it's okay, when i load my component i dispatch my action to load the state on the store.
*I think the problem is that the way i fill the state is **ASYNC***

Store:

```
import StockService from '@/services/StockService'

export const moduleStock = {
  strict: false,
  state: {
    productos: []
  },
  mutations: {
    setProductos (state, payload) {
      state.productos = payload.productos
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchProductos ({commit}, payload) {
      const resp = await (StockService.getProductos())
      var productos = resp.data
      commit('setProductos', {productos: productos})
    }
  }
}
```

When i load my component, the propertie "productos" on the data() is null, however if i see the 'state.productos' from the Vuex devtools, it has the data!

I'm messed up.

Comment: Use `productos` as a computed property, not in `data()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data() method is only run once.

This might seem to work if when the component and the vue store use the same object instance, but doesn't work in this case because a new array instance is assigned in the store while the component stil has the previous instance (the empty array)

Use [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). I recommend using the [mapState()](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) helper:

```
computed: mapState({
  productos: state => state.mStock.productos
})
```

without mapState you'd write:

```
computed: {
  productos() {
    return this.$store.state.mStock.productos
  }
}
```

Comment: And should i still keep the code inside &quot;created()&quot;?

Comment: Yes, you only want to call the `fetchProductos` once, not in the computed method which is called every time the store changes.